# How to delete composite indexes in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console, database-indexes

The documentation says :
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing

> To delete an index:
>
> ```
> Go to the Cloud Firestore section of the Firebase console.
> Click the Indexes tab.
> Hover over the index you want to delete and select Delete from the context menu.
> Confirm that you want to delete it by clicking Delete from the alert.
> ```

On current Cloud Firestore ,

- Single field index can be deleted by using right submenu
- But hovering doest work and submenu are inexistent for composite index section

I have only found a console command to delete all indexed for a firestore db

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have same issue with firestore UI web panel tho I found a solution using cloud.

First you need to enter https://console.cloud.google.com/ and select your project after that open gcloud terminal (you can access this on the top right corner nearby your avatar).

[image]

To list all your composite indexes for selected project, type this into the terminal

```bash
gcloud firestore indexes composite list
```

Then pick `id` of the one you want to remove and type

```bash
gcloud firestore indexes composite delete <composite-id>
```

It'll ask you for confirmation, once you done it by typing and entering `y` your index is gone c:

Answer (score 10):

In the Cloud Firestore UI web panel, the icon with 3 vertical dots is for some reason hidden. If you hover over the right part of the line, just right to the status field, the 3 vertical dots icon will show and hovering over that will show an option to delete the composite index for a collection.

Comment: Indeed hovering makes now the 3 vertical dots appear but previously it was not the case.I guess issue is closed.

Comment: This should be selected as the RIGHT ANSWER!